# Wireframe doesnt change to modified look when using bevel modifier

Tags: wireframe

[image: Here wireframe doesnt changed and look like basic wireframe of object]
[image: And here wireframe changed to beveled object while modifier still not applied]

What needs to be changed to make it look like in the second picture?

Comment: Please add your images directly into your question rather than just providing links to them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: The Bevel modifier is going to show the actual edges when you are in edit mode. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to manipulate them. The second picture is in Object mode

Comment: It's probably because you're in Edit mode and the second image is in Object mode but without seeing the whole window we can't really tell.

Comment: As mentioned by the others before, the second image is in _Object Mode_ - and to add, if you're wondering why then there is a wireframe visible, either it's enabled in the _Overlays_ for the viewport (which would show the wireframe on all objects) or it is enabled in the _Object Properties_ under _Viewport Display_ > _Show_ > _Wireframe_, which would only make it visible on that object.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the others before in the comments, the second image is in *Object Mode* - The beveled edges will not show in *Edit Mode*. What you need to change in *Object Mode* to make it look like that: Either enable *Geometry* > *Wireframe* in the *Overlays* for the viewport (which would show the wireframe on all objects) or in the *Object Properties* under *Viewport Display* enable *Show* > *Wireframe*, which would only make it visible on that object. By the way, using these methods the modified wireframe would also be visible in *Edit Mode*, but it is not selectable and will be shown together with the original mesh, which can be distractive for editing.

[image: wireframe visibility]